# Background property not working in my custom control derived from ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I am creating a custom control which is derived from ItemsControl and now I am facing a problem. When I try to set background of my control in the sample, it doesn't work. Below is the code for the control:

```
<!--Parent-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Parent}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Parent}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer>  
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--MainChild-->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainChild}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="430"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainChild}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--InnerChild-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:InnerChild}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:InnerChild}">
                --------------------------------------
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The base control to my custom control is

Parent-ItemsControl
MainChild-ItemsControl
InnerChild-ContentControl

In my sample, I tried to set the background as follows:

```
<local:Parent Background="Yellow" >
        <local:MainChild Background="Green">
            <local:InnerChild Content="Item1" Background="#FF008C00"/>
        </local:MainChild>
</local:Parent>
```

For both the elements derived from ItemsControl, the background property is not working.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is the `Background` of your `InnerChild` not getting set?

Comment: No, for my inner child Background property is working.

Comment: How does your parent class look like?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing the same, and I don't see a problem why it wouldn't work. So waiting to see how your Parent and MainChild classes look like, here's a few things you can do:

1. Put margins on your controls in xaml. Your innerchild might take up all the space so you actually can't see the backgroundcolors of your itemcontrols (see below nr1).
2. Name your control and try to get the background in code (see below nr2).

So try nr1:

```
<local:Parent Background="Yellow" >
    <local:MainChild Margin="20" Background="Green">
        <local:InnerChild Content="Item1" Background="#FF008C00"/>
    </local:MainChild>
</local:Parent>
```

Or try nr2:

```
Dim brush As SolidColorBrush = CType(icParent.Background, SolidColorBrush)
```

Comment: @Muthalagu: add the code for your class "parent" and/or explain a bit more clear what you mean with "the background property is not working".

Comment: Djerry- Please just create simple custom control like my one(Like above codes i posted) and check this. Then you will surely face this issue. Could you?

Comment: I can't help more if you don't show me how your control classes look like (parent, mainchild and innerchild).

Comment: Djerry- control classes look like ? means what you are expecting from me?

Comment: You should have created 3 classes called Parent, MainChild and InnerChild, of which the first 2 inherit from itemscontrol. You make a reference to it by using the "local" keyword, that's defined at the top of your xaml. I need to see how those classes look like.